# Google maps in blazor 3 stops the connection to my component

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, blazor

I'm trying to build  small app - allowing me to take 1-6 pictures and get my coordinates.
But after implementing google maps, the other functions in my app are breaking.
My google searches points me towards the google map I get through jQuery modifies the doom and makes the Blazor app drop the connection.

*Im running Blazor 3, ServerPrerendered mode*
I have spend 3 days googling on this issue now, and everything I tried have failed.

In short, when I render a google map, the other functions (like adding a picture to a model) crashes the app - so I can't click anything.

```
<div class="col-12 new-lead">
    <EditForm Model="leadModel" OnValidSubmit=@ValidFormSubmitted>
            <label for="imageInput">Take a picture</label>
            @if (imageDictionary.Count > 0)
            {

                    @foreach (var imageDataUrl in imageDictionary)
                    {
                            <div class="image-list__item" @onclick="(() => OnInputFileDelete(imageDataUrl.Key))">
                                <img src="@imageDataUrl.Key" />
                                Click to delete
                            </div>
                    }
            }
        <InputFile OnChange="OnInputFileChange" accept="image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg" id="imageInput" class="hidden"></InputFile>
        <span>@leadModel.Latitude,@leadModel.Longitude</span>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <InputText id="Latitude" @bind-Value="leadModel.Latitude" class="hidden"/>
        <InputText id="Longitude" @bind-Value="leadModel.Longitude" class="hidden"/>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn__big btn__big--white " value="Create" />
    </EditForm>
</div>
```

In my On Initialized I get the the coordionates which is set in a session, once the user logs in.
The probme is that my **OnAfterRender and OnInputFileChange conflicts at** :

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("createMap", null);
        }
    }

private async Task OnInputFileChange(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
{
    var maxAllowedFiles = 6;
    var format = "image/png";

    foreach (var imageFile in e.GetMultipleFiles(maxAllowedFiles))
    {
        var resizedImageFile = await imageFile.RequestImageFileAsync(format, 200, 200);
        var buffer = new byte[resizedImageFile.Size];
        await resizedImageFile.OpenReadStream().ReadAsync(buffer);
        var imageDataUrl = $"data:{format};base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(buffer)}";
        imageDictionary.Add(imageDataUrl, buffer);
    }
}
```

**My Jquery map is a quite simple copy/paste**

```
function createMap() {

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        var accuracy = position.coords.accuracy; console.log(latitude, longitude, accuracy);
        var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 19,
            center: coords,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            navigationControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
            },
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            styles: [
                {
                    featureType: "poi",
                    elementType: "labels",
                    stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }]
                }
            ]
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(
            document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions
        );

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude),
            icon: {
                url: "/content/images/pegman.png",
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(20, 45)
                // https://sites.google.com/site/gmapsdevelopment/
            },
            map: map,
            label: {
                color: 'transparent', // <= HERE
                fontSize: '11px',
                fontWeight: '900',
                text: 'Example Label'
            }
        });
    });
}
```

**Everything loads in fine, the UI and the map.
But when I try to add a new picture I get the errors :**

```
[2021-02-17T01:06:14.210Z] Information: Normalizing '_blazor' to 'https://localhost:44305/_blazor'.
blazor.server.js:1 [2021-02-17T01:06:14.458Z] Information: WebSocket connected to wss://localhost:44305/_blazor?id=ZK1ovXOGgNBBMwPZ1n3jVg.

[2021-02-17T01:06:17.282Z] Error: There was an error applying batch 4.
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null
    
[2021-02-17T01:06:17.307Z] Error: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.
(TypeError:Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null) ---> System.InvalidOperationException:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null at        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.InvokeRenderCompletedCallsAfterUpdateDisplayTask(Task updateDisplayTask, Int32[] updatedComponents)

[2021-02-17T01:06:17.308Z] Information: Connection disconnected.
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot send data if the connection is not in the 'Connected' State.
```

Comment: It would seem it crashes once it runs the "RequestImageFileAsync"

Answer (score 0):

solution was to add all map logic to a separate blazor component and load it into the view. That way the sockets won't break.